# Bootstrap column fill available space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need one column on the left, a group of columns on the right that don't have a set height and a row at the bottom.

This is a basic mock-up of what I currently have. How would I make the left column fill the gap between the bottom of the left column and the bottom row?

[image]

Comment: Paste a Fiddle or a Bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know how to deal with this is to use javascript, which I wouldn't recommend doing. However, if you must achieve this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="left">left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#left').outerHeight($('#row').innerHeight());
```

I have a working example in Bootply, but it won't save. Will update answer with that link as soon as the service comes back.

Comment: I got it working using this, thanks. Why wouldn't you recommend using javascript for this?

Comment: That JS line serves no purpose other than make the left match the right, which I can only imagine is for aesthetic purposes as opposed to functional. From everything I have read, it is generally frowned upon to use javascript in this way, even though you are using it to overcome a limitation in CSS. Better to alter the design of the site to match what CSS can do, as opposed to use CSS+JS to make the site match the design.